# How do I get list of only duplicate objects from a list

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

How do I get list of only duplicate objects from a list.

I have an ArrayList of objects

```
Pojo Class
Class Abc {
int id ;
String name;
Date startDate;
int rowNum;
......
}

Example Data:
id    name      startDate    rowNum
110   Art       01-Jan-2018   1
120   Art       01-Jan-2019   1
121   Science   01-Jan-2018   2
122   Computer  01-Jan-2018   3
..
190   Math      01-May-2020   40
180   Math      04-Aug-2040   40
456   Math      01-Dec-2060   40
```

Abc list contains - 4000 records or more sometimes.
I want to get id,name,startDate of duplicate rowNum in separate list.

```
Ex: List2 should contains (duplicate records only)
id    name      startDate    rowNum
110   Art       01-Jan-2018   1
120   Art       01-Jan-2019   1
.....
190   Math      01-May-2020   40
180   Math      04-Aug-2040   40
456   Math      01-Dec-2060   40
```

How do I get list of only duplicate objects from a list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract duplicate objects from a List in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164975/extract-duplicate-objects-from-a-list-in-java-8)

Comment: id's are different, they are not duplicates.

Comment: I dont think its duplicate to  Extract duplicate objects from a List in Java 8 by looking at title. The other quesiton is more specific to its own class and data

Comment: as I mentioned Duplicate should be based on rowNum not Id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. group element by row num (in a `Map<Integer,List<Abc>>`)
2. for each row num, keep elements of the list which the list size is `>= 2`
3. collect filtered/kept elements

It would give a code like :

```
List<Abc> abcList = ...;

Map<Integer,List<Abc>> elementsByRowNum =
abcList.stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(Abc::getRowNum));

List<Abc> abcWithDupList = 
elementsByRowNum.values().stream()
               .filter(v-> v.size()>=2)
               .flatMap(List::stream)
               .collect(toList());
```

You could also write that in a more compact way (without the map) :

```
List<Abc> abcWithDupList = 
abcList.stream()
       .collect(groupingBy(Abc::getRowNum))
       .values()
       .stream()  // Stream<List<Abc>>
       .filter(l-> l.size()>=2)
       .flatMap(List::stream)
       .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I am looking for java 8 streams

Comment: My explanation is for Java 8 too. I updated with a sample code.

Comment: Should it not be `flatMap(List::stream)`  instead of `.flatMap(v.stream())` when flatmapping?

Comment: @Eritrean Indeed. I forgot the lambda parameter that is `.flatMap(v->v.stream()) `

Answer (score 1):

Equality is not an universal operation, exists a lot of ways to check if two elements are equals or not. This is the reason to inject explicitly the `equality` definition.

On the other hand, your question is open to retrieve **all** duplicated elements or only one of them.

If you want only one of them, the `Set` operation is the universal solution to solve it.

Using *Java*, no standard way exists to set the custom comparator but you can do using streams:

```
xs.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(youCustomKey, minBy((a, b) -> 0)))
    .values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(toList())
```

here, you get only one for each repeated group (**including singleton elements!**).

If you wish all repeated element under `yourCustomKey` you can do

```
xs.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(yourCustomKey, toList()))
    .values().stream()
    .filter(x -> x.size() > 1)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(toList())
```

here, you get all repeated elements.

In both cases, you can set your custom `yourCustomKey`, since you say *"Duplicate should be based on rowNum"* then

```
Function<Abc, Integer> yourCustomKey = Abc::getRowNum;
```

(obviously you can avoid that definition).

As an example using strings:

```
List<String> xs = asList("aaa", "bb", "rrr", "ff", "qqqq");

List<String> ys1 = xs.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(String::length, minBy((a, b) -> 0)))
        .values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(toList());

List<String> ys2 = xs.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(String::length, toList()))
        .values().stream()
        .filter(x -> x.size() > 1)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(toList());

System.out.printf("ys1: %s%n", String.join(", ", ys1));
System.out.printf("ys2: %s%n", String.join(", ", ys2));
```

Return:

```
ys1: bb, aaa, qqqq
ys2: bb, ff, aaa, rrr
```