# How to find duplicate array list object and merge few fields with the unique key

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot

```
Person elpidio = new Person.Builder().id(3L).firstName("elpidio").secondName("gomez").ext("121").build();

Person romual1 = new Person.Builder().id(4L).firstName("romualdo").secondName("perez").ext("141").build();

Person romual2 = new Person.Builder().id(4L).firstName("romualdo").secondName("perez").ext("144").build();
```

Now I need a out put some thing like this.

```
[Person [firstName=elpidio, secondName=gomez,ext=[121]],
 Person [firstName=romualdo, secondName=perez,ext=[121,144]]]
```

I refereed to below ans. But the problem I found is that I have many property in Person, and out of that I just need to merge one fields. So the entry set is giving issue. Any suggestion in welcome.

[Extract duplicate objects from a List in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164975/extract-duplicate-objects-from-a-list-in-java-8)

[How to merge child objects in list based on duplicate parent object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221600/how-to-merge-child-objects-in-list-based-on-duplicate-parent-object)

Comment: Show us your entity class `Person`, in `Person` class for  merged property need to be a list and how you check two `Person` object is equal and need to merge ? Any identifier field/fields ? And also check your example may be it is wrong.

Comment: What should be `key` in your case?  How `firstName="elpidio"` is reassigned to `id=4` in the output?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense and output doesn't match, so I'll guess you want to "merge" based on id. What you could do: maintain a map with id being the key and `Person` being the value, look up existing values when you try to add a new element and if there is one merge the two as you see fit (e.g. only add the values of the `ext` list/set to the list/set of the existing person).

Comment: Updating my question for more readability.
So basically what i wnated is that I want to merge two firstName (Key), with Single array of  ext. May be some thing like this 
{
     firstName : romualdo,
     ext : [121,144]
}

Comment: @Thomas yes, some thing like this.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one way to do it (and probably an overly convoluted, not-so-great way that I haven't completely checked for everything). What I like about this is that it shows how to make a collector of your own, and they are fairly useful to understand those underpinnings. Hopefully the comments are explanation enough. If not, there are lots of guides on custom collectors (like [this](https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-07-java-8-creating-a-custom-collector-for-your-stream/))

```
Person elpidio = Person.Builder().id(3L).firstName("elpidio").secondName("gomez").ext("121").build();
Person romual1 = Person.Builder().id(4L).firstName("romualdo").secondName("perez").ext("141").build();
Person romual2 = Person.Builder().id(4L).firstName("romualdo").secondName("perez").ext("144").build();
Map<Long,Person> filteredPersons = Stream.of( elpidio, romual1, romual2 ).collect(Collector.of(
        HashMap::new,  // Starts with an empty list
        (result,entry) -> {
            if ( result.containsKey(entry.id)) {
                // If we already have this id in our map, we add the ext to the result list. This is assuming
                // "ext" in Person is a collection of some sort (because I don't feel like going through the
                // process of creating a new arbitrary class - in other words, that exercise is left for the
                // reader =) If you don't want dupes of ext, make sure it's a set or something else that will
                // remove dupes
                result.get(entry.id).ext.addAll(entry.ext);
            } else {
                result.put(entry.id, entry);
            }
        },
        (result1, result2) -> {
            // This handles the case where the collect is handled in parallel. How do we merge two resulting
            // maps?
            // In this case we are arbitrarily calling "result1" the version to check against, but it really
            // doesn't matter.
            for ( Map.Entry<Long,Person> person : result2.entrySet() ) {
                if ( result1.containsKey(person.getKey()) ) {
                    result1.get(person.getKey()).ext.addAll(person.getValue().ext);
                } else {
                    result1.put(person.getKey(), person.getValue());
                }
            }
            return result1;
        }));
filteredPersons.forEach( (k,v) -> System.out.println( k + " - first: " + v.first + " second: " + v.second + " " +
        "ext: " + v.ext));
```

outputs:

```
3 - first: elpidio second: gomez ext: [121]
4 - first: romualdo second: perez ext: [141, 144]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to solve this question. However you if you want the answer as per your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164975/extract-duplicate-objects-from-a-list-in-java-8).

```
            persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), toList()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(x -> {
                List<String> exFields = x.getValue().stream().map(Person::getExField).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toList());
                Person duplicatePerson = x.getKey();
                duplicatePerson.setExField(exFields);
                return duplicatePerson;
            }).collect(toList());
```

Explanation.
Here we are trying to group objects if certain fields are same in object. This can be done by overridinng the `equals and HashCode method`. like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, person.id) &&
            Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName) &&
            Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName);
}
```

With this much in place you will be able to get your `entrySet`. Keys of the `entrySet` as the duplicate object (any object with those three fields) and value will be a list containing all those duplicate objects. Now from this duplicate list you only need that exFields from each object so this is the code

```
List<String> exFields = x.getValue().stream().map(Person::getExField).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toList());
```

*Why I had to use flatMap ?*

Once you get the list of all the exFields you assign that list to your duplicate object.

```
 duplicatePerson.setExField(exFields);
```

Finally Collect.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java 8 Api Stream in order to filter them by id using a predicate or use distinct()

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html